# How to define double shortcut like GG

Tags: scripting, python, customization, shortcut

I would like to define a shortcut that allows to call a custom translate function while translating. Like <kbd>G</kbd> for Vertex move and <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> for vertex slide, my shortcut should allow <kbd>G</kbd> for Blender's translate and <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> would call my custom translate function.

I tried with a modal operator calling blender's translate function and an elif event in ('G'): my_translate but it hitting <kbd>G</kbd> while translating just doesn't do anything (no error in console output).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*After some extensive search it is possible.*

Example script:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import IntProperty, FloatProperty


class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Allow GG operator"""
    bl_idname = "object.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal Operator"

    count=0

    def modal(self, context, event):
        self.count +=1
        if self.count ==1:
            bpy.ops.transform.translate('INVOKE_DEFAULT')

        elif event.type == 'G':
            bpy.ops.transform.rotate('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
            return {'FINISHED'}

        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if context.object:

            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "No active object, could not finish")
            return {'CANCELLED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

For the key you chose (here <kbd>G</kbd>) go to the modal part of the key-binding (here in `transform.translate`) and assign "cancel" to the <kbd>G</kbd> key. 
Activate the Add-on and add a hotkey to your modal operator (for the above given script : `object.modal_operator` for <kbd>G</kbd>).
It will cancel blender's translate and the add-on will launch your custom operator just after :)

The given script calls blender's official rotation, but you can replace it by a custom written operator.

Example for this script :
[image: key config GG in transform.translate mode]

Comment: Did you see my [comment above?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3592/how-to-define-double-shortcut-like-gg#comment6213_3617)

Comment: Sorry, I had a lot to do last days. I didn't test it on 2.67 but it works in 2.69 for sure. I hit G once, it starts blender's grab, G a second time, it cancels Blender's Grab and switch to my operator. I can't ensure I'll have time to test on 2.67 as I'm really busy ATM.

Comment: Just tried official 2.69, and it's the same. It won't invoke the rotation :(

Comment: I modify my answer to make it clearer

Comment: I tested it on both Linux and Windows, it works for me with official 2.69. Hope the solution is now clearer :)

Comment: Great! I missed the Modal map. If G cancels transform, it will work.

Comment: @CoDEmanX I tried to redefine that keymap in the addon registration step, but I can't find which one to change. In the user one (there is active, addon, user keymap) there are 3 transform.translate keymap. If you have a script snippet that could do the above mentioned steps automatically on activation and restore defaults on deactivation, that would be really welcome :)

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> is not actually a keybinding, <kbd>G</kbd> starts the grab operator and that reacts on certain keytrokes while it's running modally. It uses a modal map (keymapping) for this ability.

You can edit modal maps in *User preferences > Input*, but not call arbitrary operators (in fact, only sub-operations defined by the operator in C, like Select or Deselect in Border Select op).

For python-scripted operators, there's an `event` argument passed to `modal()` and you can check for keystrokes (`event.type`, `event.value` etc.) and react in whatever way.

Detect <kbd>G</kbd> keystroke in a modal operator:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import IntProperty, FloatProperty


class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Move an object with the mouse, example"""
    bl_idname = "object.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal Operator"

    first_mouse_x = IntProperty()
    first_value = FloatProperty()

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
            delta = self.first_mouse_x - event.mouse_x
            context.object.location.x = self.first_value + delta * 0.01

        elif event.type == 'G':
            self.report({'INFO'}, "G")
            context.object.location.x = self.first_value
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
            return {'FINISHED'}

        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            context.object.location.x = self.first_value
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if context.object:
            self.first_mouse_x = event.mouse_x
            self.first_value = context.object.location.x

            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "No active object, could not finish")
            return {'CANCELLED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

---

Transform Modal Map - what (sub-)operations a possible during the modally running operators:

[image: Blender User Preferences Input Transform Modal Map]

Comment: Hi CoDEmanX, I tried with the event.type in ('G') as noted in the question, but it doesn't work, maybe I don't do it well. Could you provide a working piece of code ?

Comment: I added a quick example above, based on the Operator Modal template.

Comment: Thanks CoDEmanX, but as mentioned above, I would like the first 'G' press to use Blender's translate operator and only the second 'G' press to use a custom translate like the one you wrote. Is it possible ? Or can I only switch between 2 custom translate functions ?

Comment: Ok, I guess I wasn't clear enoug: it's not possible. Transform operators can only run a hardcoded set of (sub-)operations. See screenshot above.

Comment: I found a way, never say it's impossible ;) see my answer for details. By the way, I see it was a good idea to point you to Blender's Stackexchange website, you already earned 1000 points :D

Comment: Nice thinking! I actually used something like that (counter and C op invocation) in my Border Deselect Outer addon. It's a hack however, you need to re-bind the G key to your custom operator. And it doesn't seem to work in 2.67? All events are consumed by the grab operator, it won't recognize G keystrokes. It only does if I hit spacebar to confirm translation change, and custom modal op will continue to run and therefore receive events incl. G. 1,000 points and ongoing - yeah, I really like it here ;)