# Looping Repeatable Hotkey with Python

Tags: python, scripting, loop

I've been studying this [Dual Functionality](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141999/dual-functionality-for-a-single-hotkey-s-for-scale-similar-to-the-g-hotkey-f) question and trying to get something similar going, however for a slightly different need. I'm trying to create a hotkey that is repeatable, and cycles through 3 or more operators. Activate the hotkey once correlates with the first operator, 2 times with the 2nd operator, 3 etc, and once you hit it the last time it loops back to the 1st operator. I can get this to work with just two operators, but not 3 or more.

I'm assuming this is a failure to figure out the counting system. How does the counting system work? From my understanding

```
count=0
```

sets it to start at 0.

```
self.count+=1
if self.count ==1
```

adds a 1 to it and says "if it's 1, do this..". The final 0 in the elif

```
self.count = 0
```

sets it back to zero and thus the loop (return {'CANCELLED'} presumably). Adding additional elif statements with self.counts at higher numbers are either just skipped when I attempt to do it or break the script. What am I missing?

Comment: Paste an example code that doesn't work as you would expect it to, then we can point out where's the mistake.